# Use of HEIC files with filepond?

Tags: filepond

I'm trying to upload an HEIC file with filepond.  Which file type should I specify?

At the moment I have this:

```
  accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/jpg"
```

I can't find anything in the docs about this, and my experimentation doesn't work.

Here's the test file I'm trying to upload:

https://github.com/tigranbs/test-heic-images/raw/master/image1.heic

Answer (score 3):

Thank to @Rik for pointers.  Here is some code which does this using filepond in Vue.  Feels slightly hacky but does the job.

Accept the image/heic content type and add a custom validator:

```
<file-pond
  v-if="supported"
  ref="pond"
  name="photo"
  :allow-multiple="multiple"
  accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, image/jpg, image/heic"
  :file-validate-type-detect-type="validateType"
  :files="myFiles"
  image-resize-target-width="800"
  image-resize-target-height="800"
  image-crop-aspect-ratio="1"
  label-idle="Drag & Drop photos or <span class=&quot;btn btn-white ction&quot;> Browse </span>"
  :server="{ process, revert, restore, load, fetch }"
  @init="photoInit"
  @processfile="processed"
  @processfiles="allProcessed"
/>
```

Then in the validator check for the filename, to handle browsers that don't set the correct MIME type:

```
validateType(source, type) {
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (source.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('.heic') !== -1) {
      resolve('image/heic')
    } else {
      resolve(type)
    }
  })

  return p
}
```

Then in the process callback, spot the HEIC file and use heic2any to convert it to PNG and use that data in the upload.

```
async process(fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort) {
  await this.$store.dispatch('compose/setUploading', true)

  const data = new FormData()
  const fn = file.name.toLowerCase()

  if (fn.indexOf('.heic') !== -1) {
    const blob = file.slice(0, file.size, 'image/heic')
    const png = await heic2any({ blob })
    data.append('photo', png, 'photo')
  } else {
    data.append('photo', file, 'photo')
  }

  data.append(this.imgflag, true)
  data.append('imgtype', this.imgtype)
  data.append('ocr', this.ocr)
  data.append('identify', this.identify)

  if (this.msgid) {
    data.append('msgid', this.msgid)
  } else if (this.groupid) {
    data.append('groupid', this.groupid)
  }

  const ret = await this.$axios.post(process.env.API + '/image', data, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    onUpLoadProgress: e => {
      progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total)
    }
  })

  if (ret.status === 200 && ret.data.ret === 0) {
    this.imageid = ret.data.id
    this.imagethumb = ret.data.paththumb
    this.image = ret.data.path

    if (this.ocr) {
      this.ocred = ret.data.ocr
    }

    if (this.identify) {
      this.identified = ret.data.items
    }

    load(ret.data.id)
  } else {
    error(
      ret.status === 200 ? ret.data.status : 'Network error ' + ret.status
    )
  }

  return {
    abort: () => {
      // We don't need to do anything - the server will tidy up hanging images.
      abort()
    }
  }
},
```

The server is then blissfully unaware that the original file was HEIC at all, and everything proceeds as normal.

Comment: I used this piece of code in my case:

`const validateType = (source, type) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const heicRegExp = new RegExp('\\.(heic|heif)$', 'i');
        if (heicRegExp.test(source.name)) {
             resolve('image/heic');
        }

        resolve(type);
    })
}`

Answer (score 2):

The format is `image/heic`, I tested this using this tool: 
https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/NzRvbj

It's possible that not all browsers assign the correct mime type. You can work around that by using the `fileValidateTypeDetectType` property see here for an example:
https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-validate-type/#custom-type-detection

Please note that uploading will work, but previewing the image won't.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry for the delay in thanking you.  I've tried that property, and that does allow me to correct the MIME type.

However I then have problems on the server side, since I'm running PHP imagecreatefromstring, which doesn't handle HEIC files.

Is there any scope for running a conversion on the client side (e.g. using https://github.com/alexcorvi/heic2any) to turn it into JPG before the upload?  I'm not sure at what point I would do that.

Comment: You could set up a custom `server.process` method and detect the HEIC format there, if found, convert the file before upload. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#advanced

Comment: How do you detect and convert the HEIC image to JPG? Could any one provide an example?